# Join based on part of a varchar field matching another field

Tags: sql-server-2008, join, conditional-statements

I am looking join to do a left join on two tables. A string description on one table contains the UID of another table. I want to do the left join only if the description matches the UID. I need to return all records in the Transactions table.
Is it possible to use an IF or conditional statement to join the tables else leave the fields as null?

Here is a fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/aaa38/5

Transactions table:

```
posted_date  person_id  description 
2015-11-01    2         BZ#1414 Description 1414
2015-11-01    2         Another type of transaction with spaces in it
2015-11-01    3         BZ#1313 Another description 1313
2015-11-01    3         Another_description_without_spaces
```

Transaction_details table:

```
id    person_id   description
1414    2         additional stuff for 1414
1313    3         additional stuff for 1313
```

The results should look like:

```
posted_date person_id   description     id   person_id  description
2015-11-01   2          BZ#1414 Des...  1414    2       additional...
2015-11-01   2          Another typ...  NULL    NULL    NULL
2015-11-01   3          BZ#1313 Ano...  1313    3       additional...
2015-11-01   3          Another_des...  NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Comment: Is description always BZ# and a number followed by a space when you want to join?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joining like that really means that your Transactions table structure is not good (there should be a separate column for a field you could use to join to Transaction_details).

Having said that, you can still achieve what you want. You can join when the description starts with `BZ#` and then join on what follows, taking the length of id to extract the number. This is better than trying to find a space in the description as there may not be any spaces.

Left join will do the rest and fill the fields from tran_details with nulls if there was no match.

```
select * 
from
transactions t
left join tran_details d
on t.person_id = d.person_id
and left(t.description, 3) = 'BZ#'
and substring(t.description, 4, len(cast(d.id as nvarchar(50)))) = d.id
```

I assumed that you want to join if `BZ#` is followed by the id from the detail table.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/aaa38/16)

Answer (score 0):

The below query will work, as long as the first 3 chars are 'BZ#' in  Transaction.Description column

select * from Transactions t left outer join Transaction_details td on t.person_id = td.person_id and left(t.description, 3) = 'BZ#' and
 REPLACE(SUBSTRING(t.description, 0, CHARINDEX(' ',t.description, 0)), 'BZ#', '') = td.id